# Not apply rewrite in a Joomla subdir

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I installed Joomla in my root dir (sorry), and now I needed to install a Wordpress in my website.
Then I create a subdir called "blog" in my Joomla directory.
Until then its ok because mysite.com/blog was working.
But when I click in some post, I get a Joomla error.
As if there wasn't that page in Joomla.

What can I do?
I was thinking about a rule in my htaccess to dont affect the entire subdir "blog".
But I don't know how to do this.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Add `RewriteRule ^blog - [L]` above the Joomla rules.

Comment: Have you even read my answer? I said to put it above the joomla rules. So if you put it at the end of the file it won't work.